# How to send object from a tag

Tags: java, jsp

I am new in JSP, i have a question, i have a jsp page in this there are hiperlink,
after clicking link it navigate to def.jsp page.

issue :- i want send this person object to def.jsp page

**Abc.jsp**

```
<a href = "/def.jsp"><%person.getFirstName()%></a>
```

NOTE:- i am not getting request reference in a tag and cann't send any object from query string as i know.

if my question is clear to you, please response me.

Answer (score 0):

if the object is just between these two pages.. then you can use `<%request.setAttribute("person",person);%>` this would add the person object to the request & can be accessed as

```
<% Person p = (Person)request.getAttribute("person");%>
name is <b><%=p.getFirstName()%></b>
```

else you can put the person object in the session.. `session.setAttribute(Stirng, Object)` & `session.getAttribute(String)`

Comment: my question is:--i have multiple objects in Abc.jsp page and if i am clicking on any link then it will navigate to my on second(def.jsp) page and i want to print only that object which is clicked on Abc.jsp page

Comment: in that case.. you should use javascript .. set the clicked link value ( or some related value ) in to a hidden field & post the page to the new jsp... then you can access the data via `request.getParameter()`

Answer (score 0):

You do not pass an object, but parameters as string values.

A valid URL would be

```
/def.jsp?firstName=Prabhat
```

That would allow, in the receiving JSP, to ask for parameter "firstName" and get back "Prabhat".

Note that you should use URLEncode in your parameters in case they may have special characters (including whitespace).

Also, the '<%' tag is used to include java code, not to output. Your code is equivalent to:

```
 out.println("<a href = \"/def.jsp\">);
 person.getFirstName();
 ....
```

For "printing" the variable value, you should use '<%='

Comment: you are right, i got what you said, but neverthless i did't got my answer

Comment: i am trying, my question is:--i have multiple objects in Abc.jsp page and if i am clicking on any link or object(**link on person.getFirstName()**) then it will navigate to me on second(def.jsp) page and i want to print only that object which is clicked on Abc.jsp page

Comment: You pass the id of that object as a paremeter in the  URL (as per my answer) and in the def.jsp you retrieve it using request.getParameter(). Then you retrieve the entire object (from DB? session?) and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: person is entity object(DB) on Abc.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you wants to do

**Abc.jsp**

```
<a href = "/def.jsp?pName=<%=person.getFirstName()%>"></a>
```

**def.jsp**

```
<%
  String personName = request.getParameter("pName");
%>
Person Name:<%=personName%>
```

Comment: i want person object on def.jsp not any value